# Fetch polyline co-ordinates of a particular route from GeoJSON file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox, geojson

I have downloaded OSM file of an entire city from [Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/). Then I have converted the OSM file into GeoJSON file format. Now I want to fetch the polyline points/co-ordinates (longitude, latitude) of driving directions (from origin to destination) from that GeoJSON file. I do not want to visualize the co-ordinates on the map.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you planning to do the routing on the client side (in browser), or do you want to set up a server that will run a routing engine on the backend?

Comment: I'm planning to do the routing on the client side.

Comment: If you want to do routing on the client side with just JavaScript have a look ;) http://www.teavm.org/live-examples/graphhopper/index.html here is the code https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm-graphhopper

Answer (score 0):

[GeoJSON Path Finder](https://github.com/perliedman/geojson-path-finder) is a client-side router for GeoJSON data. Quoting from the docs:

> Given a network of GeoJSON `LineString`s, GeoJSON Path Finder will
>   find the shortest path between two points in the network. This might
>   be useful for automatic route searches in smaller networks, where
>   setting up a real route planner like OSRM is too much work, or you
>   simply need to do everything on the client.

It takes a `FeatureCollection` of `LineString` features as input, so if your GeoJSON data are structured differently, you may need to reformat a bit (and get rid of any linear features like rivers that you don't want to use as routes). The documentation also seems to indicate that the router treats all crossing features as intersections, so bridges, tunnels and overpasses may produce errors in the route.

The TeaVM GraphHopper solution that @Karussell links to in the comments may also be quite useful if you want to use a more fully-featured router client-side. There is a blog post with some details on how to implement it, [here](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/graphhopper-in-the-browser-teavm-makes-offline-routing-via-openstreetmap-possible-in-javascript/).